# How manually set stream resolution?

Tags: android, c++, c, gstreamer, rtsp

In android application I use this pipeline in gst-rtsp-server:

`"Appsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay "`

And this to receive stream:

`"rtspsrc ! Rtph264depay ! H264parse ! avdec_h264 !  autovideosink"`

And got stream with 1280x720 resolution. Where and how I can set it?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can change resolution with *capsFilter* element. You will also need extra *videoscale* element and probably *videoconvert* too.

Here is gst-launch pipeline example:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc \
! videoconvert ! videoscale \
! capsfilter caps="video/x-raw, width=640, height=480" \
! autovideosink
```